# printing list with rows and coulmns with nested for each loop in asp,net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to print data from sql to my view through viewbag,
here is the code of cs class where I added my data to list and returning in viewbag, but I want to retrieve it  5 columns in a row of table dynamically ..
so don,t understand how to set it in view with 5 column per row..

check the demo code
controller code

```
public class moviestb
    {
        public int movieid { get; set; }
        public String moviename { get; set; }
    }


 public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader rdr;
        public MoviesController()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["procon"].ConnectionString);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
           //Any Msg
            }

            con.Open();




             String   Query ="select * from movietb";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<moviestb> mov = new List<moviestb>();

            while(rdr.Read())
            {
               mov.Add( new moviestb(){movieid=Convert.ToInt16(rdr["m_id"]), moviename= rdr["m_name"].ToString()}); 
            }

        }
 ViewBag.MovieList = mov;
        con.Close();
        return View();
```

}
    view code 
    here I want 5 rows per coulmn

```
    <table>

    @foreach (var m in ViewBag.MovieList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>id = @m.Id title= @m.Title</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

here I want to set movie id , title and image in just one td .. i want 5 td per iteration , when I run above code i getting data in one row i want data like this watch this [link] (prntscr.com/k754ho)

Comment: Just use a table!

Comment: i am using a table but wants new row , next line after 5 column data , actually I'm making a shopping cart ..

Comment: There isn't a table tag in your html nor a table row tag in your for loop. How are you using a table?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a table like you have said.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.MovieList.Count; i++)
{
    <td>
        <h1>@ViewBag.MovieList.IndexOf(i)</h1>
    </td>
    <td>
        //whatever is next
    </td>
}
```

But I'm just going off that comment

Comment: here I want to set movie id , title and image in just one td .. i want 5 td per iteration , when I run above code i getting data in one row
i want data like this watch this  [link] (http://prntscr.com/k754ho)

Comment: You shouldn't use a table for these kind of elements. Try css grid layout:  [Documentation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [examples](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/)

Comment: Thanks james but can we use pagination in css grid layout?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean with "5 columns in a row of table dynamically", but you can create a table like this.

**Model**

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Service**

I would move this to a separate class.

```
    private IEnumerable<Movie> LoadMovies()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["procon"].ConnectionString;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("select * from movietb"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        yield return new Movie
                        {
                            Id = (int)reader["m_id"],
                            Title = reader["m_name"].ToString()
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var movies = LoadMovies().ToList();            
        ViewBag.MovieList = movies;
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
<table>
    <th>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Title</td>
    </th>
    @foreach (var m in ViewBag.MovieList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@m.Id</td>
            <td>@m.Title</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```